Are we able to integrate OCR using bus64 or image link with Microsoft Power Automate?
We want people to OCR in to Microsoft Power Automate and it happens but we want to present this in a dynamic way.

We use it to recognize text in an image or a PDF document and thats work properly but i am facing one issue

We want people to accept the link of the image in the database or its base64 path. If so, how will it be done??

i want OCR using base64 or image url and give output text.


If anyone has information about this, please let us know
thanks,

I OCR the image via the link and it's done.
follow steps and working done.
refrence is : Click here

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
